# Python click to restart a command with all parameters cleared

Tags: python-click

My script below is saved in 'bike.py' and registered as `bike` shell command. I'd like to run a simple `bike filter -c chicago -m 1 -d 1` command to explore data for `chicago` as city, `1` as month and `1` as day of week. I use `prompt=True` to catch any options unspecified in the command.

I'd also like to be able to restart the command at the end and have all the existing parameters cleared, so that the command will prompt me for `city`, `month` and `day of week` at restart. However, the code can't do that. It just runs what's inside the script and gives me error because the script can't run without the arguments passed in.

How should I do this with click?

```py
@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def main():
    ctx.ensure_object(dict)


@main.command()
@click.option('-city', '-c', prompt=True)
@click.option('-month', '-m', prompt=True)
@click.option('-day_of_week', '-d', prompt=True)
@click.pass_context
def filter(ctx, city, month, day_of_week):
    # load filtered data
    ...

    # restart the program
    if click.confirm('Restart to explore another dataset?') if not False:
        import sys
        sys.argv.clear()
        ctx.invoke(filter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your filter command so you do the prompting manually. I don't think Click will know to prompt otherwise, since this is not a common use-case and doesn't conform to the `no-magic` click style guide.

```py
@main.command()
@click.option('-city', '-c')
@click.option('-month', '-m')
@click.option('-day_of_week', '-d')
@click.pass_context
def filter(ctx, city, month, day_of_week):
    # prompt if not passed in
    if city is None:
        city = click.prompt('City: ')
    if month is None:
        month = click.prompt('Month: ')
    if day_of_week is None:
        day_of_week = click.prompt('Day of the week: ')

    # load filtered data
    ...

    # restart the program
    if click.confirm('Restart to explore another dataset?'):
        ctx.invoke(filter)
```

Alternatively, if you really want to rely on the built-in functionality, you might be able to get some mileage by overriding the `Option` class and prompt functionality.